# Adding file into to an existing .war file

Tags: ruby, shell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

My automation deployment environment I have web.war file deployment under tomcat.

Lets assume this web.war application contains mix.jar file which is under /lib directory of web.war archive file.

(mix.jar releases giving by different DEV team and they don't responsible for giving web.war and the organization practice is putting the latest mix.jar file into the web.war archive file manually )

Can anyone help me to automate this process from CHEF recipe ?

Basically what I need during the chef deployment is, putting the mix.jar file into the web.war/lib directory under tomcat container.

Our current practice is open the web.war file from Winrar and put the mix.jar file into it and redeploy it into tomcat.

But I want to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are just zip files so you can probably write some code using either the `zip` command line tool or the RubyZip gem (I would go for the latter but depends on your comfort level with Ruby code) to do this on the fly, but please don't. Chef is really not built for this kind of task and it will be very frustrating to build the code in a robust manner. If you need it ASAP and want to build a fragile version now and fix the process afterwards that's more understandable, but otherwise probably just talk to your dev team about what this is and why you need it added to their build process. Some problems are best solved with communication rather than code.